# How do I install fonts on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, fonts, linux-mint

I have some external fonts called Eaglefeather (Frank Lloyd Wright fonts) and I want to install them on to my Linux machine running Linux Mint 7 (Ubuntu based).  I can't seem to get them to install which looks to me like just copying them to the /usr/local/share/fonts directory.

Comment: Did you really pay $19.95 for that font?

Comment: If the font is a Truetype .ttf file then copying to a system fonts directory or your ~/.fonts should suffice. Other font types may be different. For example, an Opentype font may work with some programs but may not work with all (especially if it's a .otf file). Some programs will find it more easily if `fc-cache` is re-run and the application restarted.

Answer (score 6):

Create a folder in your home directory (ie. `~`) called `.fonts` and paste all fonts there.

*This should work since it's ubuntu based but I'm not 100% sure.*

Comment: and then don't forget to 'xset fp rehash' (telling the font-cache to reread all available fonts), after that your apps should find the new font.

Comment: this works but only installs the fonts for that user.  to make it a system-wide installation, use /usr/local/share/fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Linux Mint 8 (based on Ubuntu 9.10), there is an integrated font installer, which I describe in my blog post here:
http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/01/ubuntu-910s-integrated-font-installer.html
[image: Font installer]

Any chance you could upgrade?  It would make font installing easier.

If not, check out this Youtube video on how to install fonts in Linux Mint 7:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CseGMm3AEcw